# Generating a clock from timer using PWM

Tags: pwm, clock, timer

I am using CC2640 from TI in one of my designs. As per the datasheet, I can output a clock of maximum 32KHz to any external circuit/IC. As per my design, I Need to provide 1MHz clock to a sensor.

CC2640 has 4 32bit timers & all are PWM capable. So, my doubt is :-

1. Can I generate a 1MHz clock using timer in PWM mode?
2. How do I know what is the resolution of my timer if I am operating CC2640 on 24MHz.

Answer (score 1):

This being a newer chip from TI there is not a whole lot of application information for it as yet. Even the current [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2640.pdf) is not very helpful.

Here is one example of using the PWM capabilities of CC26XX series chips at a 1Mhz timer frequency.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/p/405132/1435673#1435673

The resolution of the Timer is determined by the base clock, the counter setup (eg.: 16 or 32 bit) and the division values being used, (per the example see the values of: PWM_DIV_FACTOR, TIMER_LOADSET, and TIMER_MATCH).

You may also want to review the TI SmartRF06 board that is mentioned in the link.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the discussion but I am looking for a more straight forward answer.